# Receive validationToken but Subscription validation request timed out

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, subscription, microsoft-graph-calendar

Anyone can help me?.
I want register subscription for user, i use ngrok.
I try use postman it success but in my web it error.
this is my log

```
[2020-07-20 11:12:52] local.INFO: Error: Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Subscription validation request timed out.",
    "inner (truncated...)
  
this is my validationToken i receive:
 array (
  'validationToken' => 'Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: d11e795b-9b06-46ff-b2ba-0df49a6e1c5c',
)
```

and my code

```
try {
            $graph = new Graph();
            $graph->setAccessToken($this->token);
            $sub = new Model\Subscription();
            $sub->setChangeType("created");
            $sub->setNotificationUrl($this->domain. '/api/receive-notification');
            $sub->setResource( "users/" . $outlook_id . "/events");
            $sub->setClientState('SecretClientState');

            $dateTime = new Carbon();
            $dateTime->addDays(3);
            $sub->setExpirationDateTime($dateTime);

            $subResult = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/subscriptions")
                ->attachBody($sub)
                ->setReturnType(Model\Subscription::class)
                ->execute();

            dd($subResult);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: are you responding to the notification endpoint validation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation

Comment: yes. that right

Comment: Can you include the code that responds to the validation?

Comment: yes. i check it in postman, everything good. but when i use code in my app. it error timed out.

Comment: Can you update your post to include the code that receives and responds the validation token please?

Answer (score 0):

Graph API only allows 4230 minutes into the future.

Change

```
$dateTime->addDays(3);
```

to

```
$dateTime->modify('+4230 minutes');
```